# Need Excel Help w/ Matching a value and then copying the data in the adjacent cell-- other questions haven't helped

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have tried a bunch of different formulas, and I can't get what I am looking for, unfortunately. I am trying to take one list of UPC's and find those UPC in the list to the left of it, then take the price next to that matching UPC and put it next to the UPC in the other list.
I have tried VLOOKUP formulas and one INDEX formula, but I don't have much experience with those and the formulas I am finding on forums don't seem to be applicable once I change the parts of the formula to match my situation.
Any help is appreciated!
Image:

[image: UPCS AND PRICES]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula in E2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$9,0),1),"")
```

$B$2:$B$9 is the column of sib_baseprice change $B$9 with the last reference in the column
 $A$2:$A$9 is the column of inv_scancode change $A$9 with the last reference in the column
D2 is the UPC Code that you need its price
IFERROR is used to return empty price if the UPC is not found in column A

Comment: That worked perfect! You are seriously a lifesaver. I hope I can return the favor  on this forum with some of my own knowledge in other areas. Thanks again!

Comment: You can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Put in cell D2 formula:
   =INDEX($A:$B;MATCH($C2;$A:$A;0);2)
Fill cells, in column D, down with this formula.